# Systemd kills autostarting service (xampp). How to prevent that?

Tags: xampp, systemd, autostart

The service `xampp.service` is not autostarting, despite being enabled. It seems that systemd is killing it after succcesful start (?).

It is located under /etc/systemd/system/ and contains the following

```
[Unit]
Description=XAMPP

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/lampp/lampp start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`systemctl --failed` returns:

```
 UNIT          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● xampp.service loaded failed failed XAMPP
```

`systemctl status xampp.service` returns:

```
● xampp.service - XAMPP
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xampp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mo 2016-11-21 02:04:10 CET; 4min 56s ago
  Process: 459 ExecStart=/opt/lampp/lampp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 459 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 21 02:02:40 tangboshi lampp[459]: XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
Nov 21 02:02:40 tangboshi lampp[459]: XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
Nov 21 02:02:40 tangboshi proftpd[600]: tangboshi - ProFTPD 1.3.4c (maint) (built Fri Aug 26 2016 11:19:40 CEST) standalone mode STARTUP
Nov 21 02:02:40 tangboshi lampp[459]: XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
Nov 21 02:02:40 tangboshi proftpd[600]: tangboshi - ProFTPD killed (signal 15)
Nov 21 02:04:10 tangboshi systemd[1]: xampp.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Nov 21 02:04:10 tangboshi systemd[1]: xampp.service: Killing process 576 (mysqld_safe) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 21 02:04:10 tangboshi systemd[1]: xampp.service: Killing process 737 (mysqld) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 21 02:04:10 tangboshi systemd[1]: xampp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 21 02:04:10 tangboshi systemd[1]: xampp.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information here to be sure but I'm guessing that `lamp start` runs the individual component services in the background and exits when they are all started. However, the default service type is simple where the process started by systemd is supposed to stay in the foreground. When the start script exits the assumption is the service has died/exited and systems cleans up the other processes running in that context. If you add `Type=forking` in the service section systemd will do the right thing. For more details see the [systemd.service man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

Comment: This indeed solved my problem, thank you very much!